# Jasmine (unit) test Angular component that uses i18next (translation) functionality - getting "No provider for InjectionToken I18NEXT_SERVICE"

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, jasmine, i18next

I'm trying to test through Jasmine (version 3.99) an Angular (version 9) component that utilizes i18next for its translations.  Note that the code for the component renders as desired when viewed through our application, however in the Jasmine test outlined below it does not (the full error message I received is listed near the bottom of the post).  Also note that I'm *not* wanting to mockup the translations or any i18next functionality - i.e. I want my component to use/render the translations as normal.  The component setup is as follows

```
constructor(@Inject(I18NEXT_SERVICE) private i18NextService: ITranslationService,
  private myTranslationTextService: MyTranslationTextService
) {
  ...
}
public ngOnInit() {
  const enTranslations = this.myTranslationTextService.getEnTranslations(); <--get translations in JSON
  i18next
    .init({
      supportedLngs: ['en',...],
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      debug: true,
      returnEmptyString: true,
      ns: [
        'translation',
      ],
      resources: {
        en: {
          translation: enTranslations
        },
        ... //other translations
      },
      interpolation: {
        format: I18NextModule.interpolationFormat(defaultInterpolationFormat),
      },
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.getData(); //<--call i18NextService methods and gets core data for MyComponent's template
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
getData() {
  this.i18NextService.changeLanguage('en'); //<--calls method within i18NextService
  ...
}
```

My spec looks like the following:-

```
export function appInit(i18next: ITranslationService) {
  //return () => i18next.init();
  return () => {
    let promise: Promise<I18NextLoadResult> = i18next.init({
      lng: 'cimode',
    });
    return promise;
  };
}

export function localeIdFactory(i18next: ITranslationService) {
  return i18next.language;
}

export const I18N_PROVIDERS = [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appInit,
    deps: [I18NEXT_SERVICE],
    multi: true
  },
  {
    provide: LOCALE_ID,
    deps: [I18NEXT_SERVICE],
    useFactory: localeIdFactory
  },
];

describe('My component', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let mock: MyMockDataService = new MyMockDataService();
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [I18NextModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        //I18NEXT_SERVICE,
        { provide: I18NEXT_SERVICE },
        //{ provide: I18NEXT_SERVICE, useValue: {} as ITranslationService },
        //{ provide: I18NEXT_SERVICE, useValue: TestBed.get(I18NEXT_SERVICE) },
        I18N_PROVIDERS,
        MyTranslationTextService
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    mockMyTranslationTextService = TestBed.inject(MyTranslationTextService) as jasmine.SpyObj<MyTranslationTextService>;
    spyOn(mockMyTranslationTextService, 'getEnTranslations').and.returnValue(mock.getEnTranslations());
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentMStep2022Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should render correctly', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  })
});
```

MyMockDataService is simply:-

```
export class MyMockDataService {
  getEnTranslations() {
    return of(
      [
        {
          "text1": "text1 EN phrase",
          "text2": "text2 EN phrase",
          ...
        }
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

However after trying a number of different options in my test - eg.

- adding I18NEXT_SERVICE to the providers list
- adding I18NEXT_SERVICE to the providers list with a initial instance - as in "{ provide: I18NEXT_SERVICE, useValue: {} }")
- as mentioned I want to use the library in the unit tests (while testing other behaviors such as how it renders, etc) so mocking I18NEXT_SERVICE isn't really an option
- https://github.com/Romanchuk/angular-i18next/issues/12 - this refers to a change an early version of angular-i18next (I'm using version 10)
- https://angular.io/errors/NG0201 - the I18NEXT_SERVICE token is injectable (InjectionToken)
- upgrading jasmine to the latest version (4.4.0)

...I am getting:-

> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[InjectionToken I18NEXT_SERVICE -> InjectionToken I18NEXT_SERVICE]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken I18NEXT_SERVICE!

To setup i18next I've followed https://github.com/Romanchuk/angular-i18next/blob/master/README.md - it refers to the test project at https://github.com/Romanchuk/angular-i18next/tree/master/libs/angular-i18next/src/tests/projectTests (note however the test project doesn't inject the i18NextService token in the constructor - injecting is the recommendation)

Can anyone shed some light ?

Comment: your spec code is not correctly formatted. a comma is missing in the describe after the first argument and the first beforeEach is not closed

Comment: What I was able to find is that if you move `init` part from the component to `APP_INITIALIZER`, then the test renders labels correctly, however it doesn't react on language change. I would assume that there is an internal trigger in the library for that, and the trigger should be called explicitly in your tests.
In that case, you can keep the code as it is, but in your test right before `detectChange` to call the trigger too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @satanTime I had the idea of add the tick() code as follows to proactively run the already queued tasks

```
describe('My component', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let mock: MyMockDataService = new MyMockDataService();
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [I18NextModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        //I18NEXT_SERVICE,
        //{ provide: I18NEXT_SERVICE },
        //{ provide: I18NEXT_SERVICE, useValue: {} as ITranslationService },
        //{ provide: I18NEXT_SERVICE, useValue: TestBed.get(I18NEXT_SERVICE) },
        I18N_PROVIDERS,
        MyTranslationTextService
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    mockMyTranslationTextService = TestBed.inject(MyTranslationTextService) as jasmine.SpyObj<MyTranslationTextService>;
    spyOn(mockMyTranslationTextService, 'getEnTranslations').and.returnValue(mock.getEnTranslations());
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentMStep2022Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should render correctly', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```